# How to get value from an Promise like Promise {_U: 0, _V: 0, _W: null, _X: null} _U : 0 _V : 1 _W : false _X : null [[Prototype]] : Object

Tags: javascript, react-native

1. *Promise {_U: 0, _V: 0, _W: null, _X: null}*

   1. **_U**: 0
   2. **_V**: 1
   3. **_W**: false
   4. **_X**: null
   5. [[Prototype]]: Object
2. 1. I want to find only Value of "false" Please help me to get it.

Comment: The promise has to resolve before you access it values. Either `await` it (in `async` context) or use promise chaining: `myPromise.then(result => { // your code });`

Comment: javascript is not java.